# how to append a div below another div and check that appended div already exists or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have created few header divs onto my html page and i want to append a div below the header div on the click of header divs but i also want to make sure that only one div is appended at a time if the div is appended on the first header on its click then on the click of second header it should be removed . i have tried toggle functionality and append function too but not getting exactly what i wanted , kindly suggest

here is my code

```
<div class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item" id="item1">
        <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox"></label></div>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-open-o folder"></i>
        <span class="name" >Introduction Document </span>
        <span class="left-more-icon"></span> 
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item" id="item2">
        <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox"></label></div>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-open-o folder"></i>
        <span class="name" >Platform details document</span> 
        <span class="right-more-icon"></span> 

    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item" id="item3">
        <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox"></label></div>
        <i class="fa fa-file-word-o word"></i>
        <span class="name" >Station list.docx</span> 
        <span class="text-muted">Jul 21, 2015  |  25 KB</span>
        <span class="right-more-icon"></span> 
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item" >
        <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox"></label></div>
        <i class="fa  fa-file-pdf-o pdf-icon"></i>
        <span class="name" >Platform details document</span> 
        <span class="text-muted">Jul 21, 2015  |  25 KB</span>
        <span class="right-more-icon"></span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my js functionality, right now on click its is appending divs to all the header divs

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.action-div-cont').hide();
        $('.list-group-item').click(function () {
            if ($('.action-div-cont').length == 0) {
                $(".list-group-item").after('<div class="action-div-cont"> <ul> <li><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Share </a></li> <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-times"></i>Delete </a></li> <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>Move/Copy </a></li> <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-font"></i>Rename </a></li> <li><a href="">More... </a></li> </ul> <div class="clearfix"></div> </div>');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Your input tags aren't closed properly. And also +1 for the T.J. Crowder comment.

Comment: its not working if i have included this nothing gets appended after the header divs

Comment: you people are their to just vote down the question , but can't come up with the answers , i did'nt find something wrong with my question

Answer (score 0):

You have a generic and specific case and you are using generic in the place of specific case.

Change your JavaScript to:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.action-div-cont').hide();
  $('.list-group-item').click(function() {
    if($('.action-div-cont').length==0) {
      // You should use this in order to get the current element.
      // this here means the current list-group-item that has been clicked.
      $(this).after('<div class="action-div-cont"> <ul> <li><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Share </a></li> <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-times"></i>Delete </a></li> <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>Move/Copy </a></li> <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-font"></i>Rename </a></li> <li><a href="">More... </a></li> </ul> <div class="clearfix"></div> </div>');
    }
  });
});
```

See the comments inside the code for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
           var $attachEle = $('<div class="action-div-cont"> <ul> <li><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Share </a></li> <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-times"></i>Delete </a></li> <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>Move/Copy </a></li> <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-font"></i>Rename </a></li> <li><a href="">More... </a></li> </ul> <div class="clearfix"></div> </div>');
            $('.list-group-item').append('<span class="right-more-icon"></span>');
            $(document).on("click",".list-group-item", function()
            {
                event.stopPropagation();
                if($(this).next().hasClass('action-div-cont')){
                $attachEle.remove();

//                    $('.right-more-icon').show();
                }
                else
                {
                    $attachEle.insertAfter($(this));
//                    $('.right-more-icon').hide();
//                    $(this).hide('.right-more-icon');

                }


              if ($(this).find('.left-more-icon').length==0) {
                  $('.left-more-icon').remove();
                 $(this).append('<span class="left-more-icon"></span>');

             }
             else
             {
                 $('.left-more-icon').remove();
             }


                if ($(this).find('.right-more-icon').length!==0) {
                    $('.right-more-icon').remove();

                }
                else
                {
//                    $('.right-more-icon').remove();
                    $(this).append('<span class="right-more-icon"></span>');
                }


            });

        })
```